# How to use mongodb as session store in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have session with more than 4KB and rails is giving me a cookieOverflow exception.

I know it's possible to use a session store to get the session information store in the DB.

In my case I use a mongoDB with mongoid.

Does anyone here know a good gem to achive my goal which is using my mongodb database as a session store ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommended redis for session store.

https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails

Comment: That would be great execpt that I am running on heroku and that my session can become quite bigger in the future.